# I am trying to loop through each item in row 1 of a sheet and delete it if it exists in a collection. But it is just not working

Tags: excel, vba

What am I doing wrong here? It just does one row, but I'm not sure why.

Please keep in mind, I am rather new at this so please dumb the answer down for me a bit. Still learning :)

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

row1 = 2

For Each sh2 In Second

    For Each Row In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A999")


            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row1, 1) = sh2 Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(row1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            row1 = row1 + 1
            Exit For

            End If

            row1 = row1 + 1

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is "Second"? You haven't included a declaration in your code. You are referring to it like it is a workbook (assuming sh2 is a sheet).

Answer (score 0):

Run the inner loop **backwards**:

```
Dim row1 As Long
    For row1 = 999 To 2 Step -1
        With Sheets("sheet1").Cells(row1, 1)
            If .Value = sh2 Then .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next row1
```

Comment: Note that by using `Exit For` to increase efficiency, OP may be expecting only one match hence the backward loop may not be necessary and the code may take far too much time. In that case, using the `Find method` or `Applicaiton.Match` may also be considered. But we don't have enough information (`sh2 = ?`, `Second = ?`) to draw any final conclusions, yet.